# Script to dynamically get Private IP of an EC2 instance

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2, ip-address, elk

I am writing an ELK deployment script and one of the things I need it to do is to edit a configuration file and insert some lines. Is there a way to make it retrieve the private IP of whichever EC2 instance the script is being run on?

For instance,let's assume that my instance's private ip is `10.0.10.154` and my script has the following lines:

`echo "  host: 10.0.10.154:9200" | sudo tee -a /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`

Is there a way to make my script dynamically retrieve and replace `10.0.10.154` with the private IP of whichever instance the script is being ran on?

Or, if each user creates a .profile file on their machine and and describe the private IP of the instance `ELK_Private IP: 10.0.10.254` or whatever their iP is - how can I retrieve this value into my script and input into the yml config file?

Comment: You should be able to find it in the `ifconfig` output.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you local IP address  :

```
curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4
```